# stack of piles visible from top view

Tags: algorithm

[image: note bundle]

This is an interview question.

Here are the notes arranged in the following manner as depicted in the image.
Given the starting and ending point of each note.

for eg. [2-5], [3-9], [7-100] on a scale of length limits 0-10^9
in this example all three notes will be visible.

we need to find out, when viewed from top, how many notes are visible??

I tried to solve in O(n*n) , where n is the number of notes by checking every note visibilty with every other note. but in this approach how will we determine if the two notes are in different stacks.
ultimately did not reached the solution.

O(n) solutions will be preferred as O(n) solution was demanded by interviewer

Comment: How are you supposed to know which range is on top of which?

Comment: This is exactly the problem i faced in O(n*n) solution

Comment: No, I mean there's not sufficient information here.  Is [3-9] at the top, or at the bottom?

Comment: the order in which the input is entered 
first one is at the top then second one below it and so on..

Comment: @Oliver:Am i wrong somewhere to explain you properly the question or it's just incomplete question?

Comment: Removed C++ tag. If you want help with your C++ code, show it.

Answer (score 0):

If O(n log n) is sufficient: first, remap all numbers in the input to between 0..(2*n+1) (that is, if a number x_i is the j-th smallest number among all numbers in the input, replace all x_i with j). You can then use Painter's algorithm on a segment tree.

Details:

Consider an array of size (2 * n + 1). Initialize all these cells with -1.

Painter's algorithm: Iterate the bank notes from the last one given (in the bottom) to the topmost one. For each note covering from a_i to b_i, replace the values of all cells in the array whose index is between a_i and b_i with i. At the end of this algorithm, we can simply look at which indexes are in the array and these form all the visible notes. However, naively this works in O(N^2).

Segment tree: So, instead of using an array, we use a segment tree. The operations above can then be done in O(log N).

Comment: can you please explain in some more detail?

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the notes in the input is "the former is on top" than its easy:

keep values of the min_x and the max_x, initializing it to the first note's x values. Iterate over the notes, each note that has x values either greater than max_x or lesser than min_x changes those respective value to its own x values and is considered visible, otherwise it is not. finish iterating and return the list of visible notes. collect the cash.